# Demistify string.format in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I know what I'm going to ask is silly. 
So here it goes. I have a C# code where I have a string as shown below:

```
string.Format(
    "{0}\"icon\":\"{2}\",\"alert\":\"{3}\",\"governanceType\":\"{4}\"{1}", 
    "{", 
    "}",    
    "notificationicon", 
    governanceName, 
    tips.GovernanceType)
```

Would any one explain would the above code mean.

Comment: The first parameter is the format-string which contains placeholders `{}`. These placeholders contain an index starting with zero. The second parameter in `String.Format` belongs to index=0, the third parameter to index=1 and so on. So `{0}` will be replaced with `"notificationicon"` and `{1}` will be replaced with `governanceName`.

Comment: @GrantWinney He does, look closely, 0 and 1 are curly brackets

Comment: @GrantWinney There are enough.

Comment: Are we constructing a JSON object here?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That seems like the best answer so far... :)

Comment: @Chris except that `{0}` will be replaced with "{" and `{1}` by "}"

Comment: -1. Did you even try to find the answer first? Normally "what does ____ do?" questions are a waste of time.

Comment: @juharr: i've overlooked that `"{"` is the first parameter. Now that the question is reformatted it's more clear. OP should read the documentation where it is explained in detail. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter yeah, I missed it too the first time I reformatted.

Comment: @juharr: Embarrassingly I didn't read that far. I got as far as the explanation of what the parameters to the method meant and how they lined up and liked that a lot. I skipped the worked example because I knew how it worked. I should read properly before recommending I guess. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) replaces tokens in a string with the values denoted the zero-based index of subsequent parameters.

Comments added for clarity:

```
string.Format(
    "{0}\"icon\":\"{2}\",\"alert\":\"{3}\",\"governanceType\":\"{4}\"{1}", 
    "{",                // {0}
    "}",                // {1}
    "notificationicon", // {2}
    governanceName,     // {3}
    tips.GovernanceType)// {4}
```

However, the brace values are presumably only there to avoid an error. A clearer solution is to escape them:

```
string.Format(
    "{{\"icon\":\"{0}\",\"alert\":\"{1}\",\"governanceType\":\"{2}\"}}", 
    "notificationicon", // {0}
    governanceName,     // {1}
    tips.GovernanceType)// {2}
```

Comment: The comments add clarity but only really if you already know what the code means. This doesn't really explain what the code does in any way which is the question.

Comment: @Chris well the code actually sends a push notification to a device using the string format above

Comment: @iJay: My point was that your question was asking what the string format meant which until the latest edit I didn't personally consider it to be doing. What you do with it after that is your business. :)

Comment: anything wrong with this answer. Saw a negative vote

Comment: @iJay - I think the votes were based on the original edit (which was light on context)

Comment: Mine wasn't the negative vote but the -1 definitely did come in before the first (in my opinion key) paragraph was added.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, the first parameter is the string to be formatted, and all subsequent parameters will be inserted at the locations of the placeholders, denoted by `{x}` in the format string (where x is an indexing integer). The frequent `\`s in the format string are *escape characters* that prevent inline `"`-characters from ending the string (they are instead printed literally).

Answer (score 1):

Format allow to build string with arguments in {} instead of concatenating ("+ var + "). Fromat is more readeble than concatenating . In your case 4 arguments:

```
{0} = "{"
{1} = "}"
{2} = "notificationicon"
{3} = value of governanceName
{4} = value of tips.GovernanceType
```

Finally arguments {} will replaced by values and you will get new frormatted string

Answer (score 0):

To make it more readable and comprehensible I have replaced the `"` char with the `'` char.
The command could be thus simplified like this:

```
string.Format("{{'icon':'notificationicon','alert':'{0}','governanceType':'{1}'}}", 
                governanceName, tips.GovernanceType);
```

When I add `.Replace('\'','\"')` to it then it produces following string (assuming that governanceName="SomeGovernanceName", tips.GovernanceType="SomeGovernanceType"):

```
{"icon":"notificationicon","alert":"SomeGovernanceName","governanceType":"SomeGovernanceType"}
```